# Сколько раз исполняется под запрос?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу понять, под запрос исполняется на каждую строку записи, или один раз, к примеру `id IN (SELECT id FROM table WHERE status="active")`?

Comment: Смотрите план запроса для начала (подробный). По идее, если подзапрос не зависит от конкретной записи или других данных в основном запросе), то оптимизатор должен сделать так, чтобы выполнить его 1 раз.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать. Перенесите в основной ответ отмечу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите план запроса для начала (подробный). По идее, если подзапрос не зависит от конкретной записи или других данных в основном запросе), то оптимизатор должен сделать так, чтобы выполнить его 1 раз